# Variable does not exist even though declared at top of apex file?

Tags: apex, visualforce

The apex class in question

```
public with sharing class myController {

    Public String searchstring{get;set;}
    Public List<Custom__c> myobjlist{get;set;}
    Public Custom__c myobj{get;set;}

    public static void nextpage(){
        System.debug(selectedpayor);
    }
```

The visualforce page?

```
<apex:page controller="myController"> 
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myobjlist}" var="singleObj"> 
    <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:commandButton value="Select {!singleObj.Name}" action="{!nextpage}">
            <apex:param value="{!singleObj.Name}" assignTo="{!myobj}"/>
        </apex:commandButton>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:page>
```

I don't really know what's wrong with it. I included in the visualforce page code in case the apex:param assignTo was somehow screwing it up but I'm not sure if it is (but what do I know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different scopes, an "instance" and a "static" scope. Instance methods can access static variables (because there may be many instances, but there will only ever be one static variable), while static methods cannot access instance variables (because there is no instance to refer to). In other words, your method, being static, can't see the instance variables. Remove the "static" keyword to allow the variable to be visible.

```
public void nextpage(){
```

Comment: Do you know why my System.debug is outputting null? I tried doing <apex:param value="{!singleObj}" assignTo="{!myobj}"/> as well but I still got null

Comment: @user49458 Two things: (a) you should specify a "name" attribute to your param (`<apex:param name="payor" ...`), and (b), you're trying to assign a Name to a type of record, which simply won't work (it's not a record, it's a String). Consider using Id instead of name, and change your data type (`public Id myObjId { get; set; }` ... (`value="{!singleObj.Id}" assignTo="{!myObjId}"`).

Comment: I'll probably ask a new question on stackexchange since the assignto is  a new question but thanks for your help on the static part!

Comment: @user49458 You're welcome. Glad I could help!